# How to evaluate performance of Word2Vec?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I want to know an effective way to evaluate my word2Vec model performance so that I can properly tune my hyper-parameters.

For example, if I were to do document classification with supervised learning, the model performance evaluation is easy, because I can just compare the predicted label to the pre-defined label for test data set.

But I'm not sure how to do so with Word2Vec. Can anyone explain how it can be done, with codes, or provide a link to a page that does this?

Please don't put a link to a paper... I'm really tired of reading difficult papers.

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation should be always task-dependent. So, if you have a particular task in mind that you would like to solve using word2vec, you should evaluate the embeddings on the task.

In general, there are some benchmark tasks for more general word representation evaluation, you can try [`word-embeddings-benchmarks`](https://github.com/kudkudak/word-embeddings-benchmarks) that probes the embeddings on several tasks including semantic similarity or sentiment classification. You can then compare your numbers with the performance of more less [standard methods](https://github.com/kudkudak/word-embeddings-benchmarks/wiki). If you are interested more on representation properties on the sentence level (e.g., averaged vectors from an entire sentence), you can try [SentEval](https://github.com/facebookresearch/SentEval).